# AIMD and velocity scaling in VASP

Tags: molecular-dynamics, vasp, ab-initio-calculations, aimd

Typically one does velocity scaling to "heat" their sample with MD.

1. How do we do this in VASP? Is it by setting the `SMASS=-1` and `MDALGO=0` tags?
2. Why can't we "heat" using a Nose-Hoover thermostat? `SMASS=0`, `MDALGO=2`?

*when I tried both methods for "heating" (100 to 600 K) I found the total E increases in method 1 and decreases in method 2. Why is this the case? I'd expect energy to rise since I started in my ground state configuration. I'm using an NVT ensemble by the way (`ISIF=2`).

Edit: I think my post was too long before so I simplified it

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out parts of my question. But would really benefit from a VASP/AIMD expert weighing in.

1. This appears to be the correct way of doing velocity scaling in VASP. And you can scale the velocity every `NBLOCK` steps (but I'm not sure if/when it's more appropriate to scale every 1 step, 10 steps, etc.)
2. Technically you can I think. I set the parameters listed in my question. And also `TEBEG = 100` and `TEEND = 600`. The temperatures and energies rose. I just don't know if this is correct to "heat" this way since I normally see people just do a constant temperature with a Nose-Hoover thermostat and NVT ensemble

*the total E actually decreased in method 2 because the potential energy of the bath decreased. So technically I should just look at E0+EK (the potential + kinetic energy), which does increase as the "temperature increases".